# How to create3d Text in android

Tags: android, animation, text, 3d, rotation

I have been trying to create 3d text like this photo

For the purpose i wrote the following code. Its almost 3d when we see it from front but if rotate it at x axis there is a point it disappears at 90 degree.
There are few apps on store too for 3d texts.
 I am first converting text to bitmap then applying overlays to give 3d effect.

```
 img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    skBar= (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
    bm = textAsBitmap("TEXT CHECK", 140.0f, Color.BLUE);
    img.setImageBitmap(overlay(bm,bm));
    skBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            img.setRotationY(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(progress)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });


 public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    for (float i = 20; i > 0; i-=0.5f) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, i, i, null);
    }
    for (float i = 1; i <= 20; i+=0.5f) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, i, i, null);
    }
    return bmOverlay;
}
public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(textColor);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paint.setTextScaleX(1.5f);
  //  paint.setTexth(5.0f);
    float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
   int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether any of the libraries from below link helps

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/101